# ASP.NET help Keyword not supported: 'data source'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Background information: I'm trying to follow the tutorial for an ASP.NET site found at [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-221c01f5?cdn_id=2013-12-16-001).

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

The only thing I've changed is the namespace names, otherwise I think I followed it.

This is the error message when I attempt to launch the site

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Keyword not supported: 'data source'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data
>   source'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5764228
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +27
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +94
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +254
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +79
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +289
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +36
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +360
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +38
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +99
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewPagedDataSource.GetEnumerator() +459
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateItemsWithoutGroups(ListViewPagedDataSource dataSource, Boolean dataBinding, InsertItemPosition insertPosition, ArrayList keyArray) +383
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +2322
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +98
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +80
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +168
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +122
>   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4775

Comment: Post your connection string

Comment: Your problem may comes from DB connection string inside web.config or wrong usage of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`. Post them both to clarify the issue.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I'm very new to asp.net but I think this is what you're asking for:

<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-jhucomics-20170103225437;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-jhucomics-20170103225437.mdf" />

    <add name="jhucomics"
 connectionString="Data
Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\jhucomics.mdf;Integra
ted Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I think your data source values are not escaped correctly, try "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\v11.0;" and "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;"

Comment: @RamblinRose thank you for the suggestion but that didn't change anything

Answer (score -1):

Try server instead of data source in you web config